# How to get access to signed in google user in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How Do I get the email of the signed in google user from my react js?

```
function App() {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, input]);
    setInput('');
    db.collection('todos').add({
      task : input,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
  }
```

Comment: You ask them to login with the Google account, after setting up a client auth key with Google, and Google will give it to you after they login in successfully. Any other methods will likely be for malicious purposes.

Comment: Is there a way to get the email of the current signed in user in the browser?

Comment: Without more information, it's hard to say beyond what I have already said.